# How can i override the capture templates in a custom call of org-roam-node-find?

Tags: config, org-roam

I am trying to streamline the process of creating a project node in org-roam. I've defined a custom wrapper function for org-roam-node-find with the following code:

```
(defun my/org-roam-filter-by-tag (tag-name)
  (lambda (node)
    (member tag-name (org-roam-node-tags node))))

(defun my/org-roam-find-project ()
  (interactive)
  ;; Select a project file to open, creating it if necessary
  (org-roam-node-find nil nil
   (my/org-roam-filter-by-tag "Project")
   :templates
   '(("p" "project" plain "* Goals\n\n%?\n\n* Tasks\n\n** TODO Add initial tasks\n\n* Dates\n\n"
      :if-new (file+head "%<%Y%m%d%H%M%S>-${slug}.org" "#+title: ${title}\n#+category: ${title}\n#+filetags: Project")
      :unnarrowed t))))
```

According to the documentation string for `org-roam-node-find` I should be able to provide a keyword argument `templates` (as I did) to override the normal org roam capture templates.

However, when I invoke this function I get the following error:

```
Keyword argument ((p project plain * Goals

%?

* Tasks

** TODO Add initial tasks

* Dates

 :if-new (file+head %<%Y%m%d%HM%S>-${slug}.org #+title: ${title
#+category: ${title}
#+filetags: Project) :unnarrowed t)) not one of (:templates)
```

Template overriding in `org-roam-capture-` works fine and I am overriding templates that way in other functions. If I define `my/org-roam-find-project` without trying to override the templates it works, but adds the friction of needing to choose a template each time I am creating a new project node through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error message again:

```
Keyword argument … not one of (:templates)
```

You supplied some arguments to this function, and it assigned most of them to the required and optional argument names, then looked at what was left over to see if they matched the available keyword arguments. The value in the error message isn’t even a keyword, which is a good indication that you have an off–by–one error in your code.

The signature for this function is:

```lisp
(org-roam-node-find &optional OTHER-WINDOW INITIAL-INPUT FILTER-FN PRED &key TEMPLATES)
```

It takes four optional arguments, plus one keyword argument. Looking at the code you quoted, it is easy to see that it took `:templates` to be the fourth optional argument (`PRED`), when that should have been the start of the keywords. Pass in `nil` for `PRED` instead.

Comment: Wow, i feel foolish for missing that. I assumed that keyword arguments would skip remaining unspecified args since the function was working fine when nothing was provided. I guess that's just implicitly giving nil to PRED though.